# Can i convert a string into a KQL command?

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

Is there such a function "**run_query**" that will convert string input into KQL code?

```
SampleTable
| extend results = run_query(Query)
```

Comment: Does the answer below help, or you need more info?

Answer (score 1):

No. But if you plan to run the query from some programming language, then you can use Kusto's SDK (available in multiple languages) to run a query from a string that you pass. See more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/about-the-sdk

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it, using PowerShell API "Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery" and then extracting the query and execute it again, but you will need some basic scripting skills with powershell

The other way is to use regex and extracts the content of the query into a variable and run it within the same query